# Error formulario php a servidor real

Tags: php, html, sql

tengo un problema,  y es que al intentar hacer un formulario para agregar valores, el formulario se queda en la misma pagina .php y no hace caso a ningun if ni else..

Mensajes.php ->

formulario :

```
<form action="mensajes.php">
    <input type="text" name="alias" class="input">
    <input type="text" name="publio" class="input">
    <input type="text" name="publit" class="input">
    <input type="text" name="personas" class="input">
    <input type="text" name="lugar" class="input">
    <input type="text" name="remitente" class="input">
    <input type="text" name="destinatario" class="input">
    <input type="date" name="data">
    <input type="submit" value="dale" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 
    include('conexionbd.php');
    session_start();    
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $alias = $_POST['alias'];
            $publio = $_POST['publio'];
            $publit = $_POST['publit'];
            $personas = $_POST['personas'];
            $lugar = $_POST['lugar'];
            $remitente = $_POST['remitente'];
            $destinatario = $_POST['destinatario'];
            $data = $_POST['data'];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO publicaciones (id,alias,publi_original,publi_traducida,personas_implicadas,lugar,dataa,remitente,destinatario) VALUES ('dummy','$alias','$publio','$publit','$personas','$lugar','$data','$remitente','$destinatario')";                
                $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
                $filas = $resultado->num_rows;
                if($filas>0){
                        echo "bien";
                    }else{
                        echo "Error al agregar mens";
                    }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Te falta agregar el method al form <form action="mensajes.php" method="post">

Comment: Madremia, habia olvidado totalmente de poner el metodo Jajaj, Muchas gracias Camilo!

Comment: Por cierto, como hago para cerrar la pregunta, y ponerte a ti como que la has resuelto?

Comment: Te voy a publicar una respuesta con una explicación más detallada dle problema, luego la aceptas y listo ! Dame unos minutos

Comment: Camilo, el formulario ya funciona, Gracias por la explicación, pero aquí tengo otra duda y es la siguiente, por que me salta al else? teoricamente debería saltarme al if, no al else.. mira

`$resultado = $conexion->query($sql);


    $filas = $resultado->num_rows;


    if($filas>0){
      echo "bien";
     }else{
      var_dump($sql);
      echo "Error al agregar mens";
     }
`

Comment: La etiqueta `form` por defecto usa el método `GET`, para que funcione por `POST`, como se puede ver en tu código debes añadir el método `POST`, es decir, `<form method="POST" action="mensajes.php">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente de falta pasar el atributo `method` a tu `<form>`.

El atributo `method` puede recibir dos valores `method="get|post"`. Cuando olvidas colocar este atributo a la etiqueta `<form>` los datos se enviarán de forma predeterminada por método `get` y como en PHP los estás recibiendo como si vinieran por método `post` entonces se genera ese conflicto que has tenido.

```
<form action="mensajes.php" method="post">
```

Por otra parte la condición nunca se te va a cumplir por que estás haciendo un `INSERT` y no un `SELECT`, cuando haces un `INSERT` el sistema te devuelve simplemente `true` si fue exitoso o `false` en caso contrario, entonces la validación debes hacerla de la siguiente manera:

```
if($resultado){
   echo "bien";
}else{
   echo "Error al agregar mens";
}
```